# answers sometimes in test, sometimes in answer file

Tags: include, content-replication

So this is going to sound strange, but I'm wondering if there is a clean way to do this.

By the time I have a project done, I will have written two .tex files: one with questions, and another one with solutions. For purposes of peer review, I'd like to know if there's a way for me to use `\include` so that if each question and solution to each respective question spans only one page, the question and solution will be paired together so that the question is first and the solution is second.

Is there a way (or a better way) to do this beside manually copying/pasting code?

MWE:

Questions:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Mock Exam}
\end{center}
\begin{enumerate} 
\item Here's a question.
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]
\item Option A
\item Option B
\item Option C
\item Option D
\item Option E
\end{enumerate}
\newpage  
\item Here's another question.
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]
\item Option A
\item Option B
\item Option C
\item Option D
\item Option E
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Solutions:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{SOLUTION}
\end{center}
\begin{enumerate} 
\item (A)

\vspace{0.2cm}
-Some stuff telling you why the answer is (A)-
\newpage 
\item (C)

\vspace{0.2cm}
-Some stuff telling you why the answer is (C)-
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This is the general way I have been creating MC exams and solutions in the past for the company, and it's still very early in the project, so I can change the code so that it works if necessary. It's just that I found it very time-consuming to copy-and-paste the solutions into a new file for peer review.

Comment: This depends on the nature of your `.tex` code, how the questions and solutions are defined. Are they coming one after another one, i.e. question 1, question 2... and solution 1, solution 2... etc.? Are they contained in environments. Please post a MWE what you already have.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can post it up due to copyright reasons. The only environment I'm using is the `enumerate` environment to group the questions and solutions by number. Everything else is just text.

Comment: Well, you can make a file with some dummy questions and one with corresponding (dummy ;-) solutions? But am unsure about that `enumerate` approach.

Comment: Sure, let me get something written.

Comment: For sure..., we will be waiting here for it.

Comment: You could use pdfpages to mix the two pdfs.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The questions are in one `enumerate` and the solutions as well, as far as I understand it, this would be difficult to break into pages to be included pagewise, or am I misled?

Comment: See the MWE. Note that it's still early in the project, so I can change the code if necessary.

Comment: @Clarinetist: Although I am thrilled to find a solution, I fear, questions organised in enumeration lists (I mean the top level enumerate, not the A) etc. options) is quite difficult. Perhaps the package `exsheets` is a better way to do it?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use something like the `answers` package so that you can keep the questions and the answers in the same source file, but compile them to either one or two pdfs as you wish - see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186530/package-answers-is-it-possible-to-append-all-solutions-to-one-output-file/186565#186565. For a simple partial solution, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97904/toggle-visibility-of-solutions-in-latex-output-for-exams/97912#97912.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: If there is something sensible and identifiable that separates the questions and answers (\item, \begin{enumerate}, \newquestion, \newsolution) it should be possible to redefine it to get a pagebreak. If there are labels one could use them to insert the correct answer.

Comment: @EthanBolker - I've never heard of such of a thing! Definitely checking it out. I would appreciate it if you could provide an answer and elaborate!

Comment: The answers in the links in my comment do provide code. If either works for you, please edit the title of your question. Then it can be marked as a duplicate, so readers who come here will know to look there.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the background to be able to easily extend what the links have to the project I'm doing.

Comment: In particular, I don't know how I would create separate .pdf files for the answers and questions using that package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That was indeed my first idea (redefining the enumerate list items), but I still had/have not enough time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{question-01}
What is an aardvark?\par
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{answer-01}
\pagebreak
The aardvark Orycteropus afer is a medium-sized, burrowing, nocturnal mammal 
\end{filecontents}

% questions and answers here
\input{question-01}
\input{answer-01}
\end{document}
```

I suggest first to define your requirements clearly, experiment with a main file first and then extend with macros and a *naming scheme* for the files. I would keep all the answers and questions of one exam in one *main* file as above. However I would recommend the individual questions and answers are kept in separate files. This way you can mix and match as you go. Keep everything in one directory and name the directory like `maths-exam-101-summer-14`.

Note you can also relate the files to `\jobname` as follows:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-01-answer}
\pagebreak
The aardvark Orycteropus afer is a medium-sized, burrowing, nocturnal mammal 
\end{filecontents}

\input{question-01}
\input{\jobname-01-answer}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! I was also able to figure out how to get `enumerate` to work with this - for people who are interested, I used `\begin{enumerate}[resume] \item` before each question and `\end{enumerate}` after each question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a substantial reworking of my original solution - there were fun problems to solve, so I'm posting it even though there's an accepted answer.

The MWE below produces these pdfs as output:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Here are the source files.

First, the test, which you must compile twice to get the references right.

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{testpreamble}

%\toggletrue{showanswers} % this is the default
\togglefalse{showanswers}

\begin{document}

\testname{Mock Exam}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Compute $2 + 2$.

\begin{choices}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4 \correct{Count on your fingers.}
\item 5
\end{choices}

\item Compute $e^{i\pi}$.

\begin{choices}
\item $e$
\item -1
\correct{
There are several ways to go about proving that

\begin{equation*}
e^{i\pi} = -1
\end{equation*}

but for this exam just \emph{knowing} the answer gets full credit.
}

\item $\pi$
\item whatever
\end{choices}

\item What is the name of this test?
\begin{choices}
\item There is no way to tell
\end{choices}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This document `answerkeymaster.tex`, produces the answer key:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\input{answerkey}
\end{document}
```

The mechanism is all hidden in the `testpreamble.tex`, which is the same for all tests:

```
% testpreamble
%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% decide whether answers appear in the test
\newtoggle{showanswers}
\toggletrue{showanswers}

% does the current question have an answer?
\newtoggle{hasanswer}
\togglefalse{hasanswer}

% file containing answer key is written
\newcommand{\answerkeyfilename}{answerkey}
\newwrite\answerkey
\immediate\openout\answerkey=\answerkeyfilename

\newcommand{\testname}[1]{%
\begin{center}
\textbf{#1}
\end{center}
\immediate\write\answerkey{%
\noexpand\begin{center}
\noexpand\textbf{#1}
\noexpand\par
Answer Key
\noexpand\end{center}
}}

% explanatory words that accompany each answer
\newcommand{\theexplanation}{}

\newcommand{\answer}{%
 \iftoggle{hasanswer}{%
   \immediate\write\answerkey{\noexpand\par\theenumi -- \ref{answer:\theenumi}}
   \iftoggle{showanswers}{%
      \par\emph{Answer}: 
      \ref{answer:\theenumi}
      \theexplanation{}}
   {} % don't show answers
  }
  {\immediate\write\answerkey{\noexpand\par\theenumi -- no answer}
   \iftoggle{showanswers}{%
      \par\emph{Answer}: none }
    {} % don't show nonanswer
  }
}

\newcommand{\correct}[1]{%
 \toggletrue{hasanswer}
 \label{answer:\theenumi}
 \global\renewcommand{\theexplanation}{#1}
}

\newenvironment{choices}
{\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]}
{\answer{}\end{enumerate}}
```

You can probably improve your workflow by implementing some of @YiannisLazarides naming conventions for your tests.

Comment: Actually, as good as this solution is, it doesn't work for my purposes. Next to the numbers (1) and (2) are the questions and next to (A), (B), (C), etc. are the Multiple Choice options. The answers are then placed on a new page, but what you said can easily be extended to that. However, the problem remains if I want to make a question-only document, which contains everything except the solutions (i.e., just the question and the MC options).

Comment: I have tried creating a new environment which hides the questions, but they seem to hate being around the enumerate `item`s.