# Enumerate pattern: 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ... , etc

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, filecontents

This is a follow-up question to [answers sometimes in test, sometimes in answer file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191397/include-on-every-other-page/191428#191428).

I went with what the best answer suggested and surrounded each question and answer by `\begin{filecontents}{some title}` and `\end{filecontents}`, giving a code similar to this here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Mock Exam}
\end{center}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{question-01}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Here's a question. \par
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]
\item Option A
\item Option B
\item Option C
\item Option D
\item Option E
\end{enumerate}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{question-02}
\pagebreak
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Here's another question.\par
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]
\item Option A
\item Option B
\item Option C
\item Option D
\item Option E
\end{enumerate}
\end{filecontents}

\input{question-01}
\input{question-02}
\end{document}
```

This works for **question numbering** (i.e, it assigns the questions the correct numbers), but what will happen once I bring in the solutions? If I add this code in:

```
\begin{filecontents}{solution-01}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item (A)\par

\vspace{0.2cm}
-Some stuff telling you why the answer is (A)-\par
\end{enumerate}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{solution-02}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item (C)\par

\vspace{0.2cm}
-Some stuff telling you why the answer is (C)-\par
\end{enumerate}
\end{filecontents}
```

and then insert where the solutions need to go, then I'll get

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Mock Exam}
\end{center}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{question-01}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Here's a question. \par
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]
\item Option A
\item Option B
\item Option C
\item Option D
\item Option E
\end{enumerate}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{question-02}
\pagebreak
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Here's another question.\par
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]
\item Option A
\item Option B
\item Option C
\item Option D
\item Option E
\end{enumerate}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{solution-01}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item (A)\par

\vspace{0.2cm}
-Some stuff telling you why the answer is (A)-\par
\end{enumerate}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{solution-02}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item (C)\par

\vspace{0.2cm}
-Some stuff telling you why the answer is (C)-\par
\end{enumerate}
\end{filecontents}

\input{question-01}
\input{solution-01}
\input{question-02}
\input{solution-02}
\end{document}
```

which is unfortunately going to give the following numbering:

1. Question 1
2. Solution 1
3. Question 2
4. Solution 2

I need the numbering to be

1. Question 1
1. Solution 1
2. Question 2
2. Solution 2

Any ideas?

FYI: I do not want to assign these questions and solutions hard values - they may need to be moved around.

Comment: I'd use a dedicated package like [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) for this...

Comment: From the `exsheets` document: "On the other hand ExSheets doesn’t – and probably won’t – offer a real possibility for creating multiple choice questions. As a fact it doesn’t provide many (if any) means to specify the type of question or the structure. If these are your needs take a look at `examdesign` [Ale01], for example. Or exploit the possibilities `enumitem` [Bez11] gives you." `examdesign`, at a first glance, isn't meant to display exam solutions.

Comment: As a note, I'm not a professor (I work for a study materials company), so I don't have much flexibility as to how I can design the question and solution files.

Comment: you're already using `enumitem`. It can be used with `exsheets` without problems. The comment means that `exsheets` does not define own environments for multiple choice lists like e.g. the `exam` class does. OTOH `exsheets` has *very* customizable question headings so it's possible to create *a lot* of different layouts with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dedicated environments for both questions and solutions. This is easy by using `enumitem`s `\newlist` and `\setlist`. This has an extra bonus: your code will have more semantic markup:

```
\newlist{question}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{solution}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[question,solution]{label=\arabic*.}
```

For your list of choices I'd also define a new list:

```
\newlist{choices}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[choices]{label=(\Alph*)}
```

A complete example (where I've removed the `\pagebreak` in order to get a shorter example):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{choices}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[choices]{label=(\Alph*)}

\newlist{question}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{solution}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[question,solution]{label=\arabic*.}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{question-01}
\begin{question}[resume]
  \item Here's a question.
  \begin{choices}
    \item Option A
    \item Option B
    \item Option C
    \item Option D
    \item Option E
  \end{choices}
\end{question}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{question-02}
\begin{question}[resume]
  \item Here's another question.
  \begin{choices}
    \item Option A
    \item Option B
    \item Option C
    \item Option D
    \item Option E
  \end{choices}
\end{question}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{solution-01}
\begin{solution}[resume]
  \item (A)\par\medskip
  -Some stuff telling you why the answer is (A)-
\end{solution}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{solution-02}
\begin{solution}[resume]
  \item (C)\par\medskip
  -Some stuff telling you why the answer is (C)-
\end{solution}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Mock Exam}
\end{center}

\input{question-01}
\input{solution-01}
\input{question-02}
\input{solution-02}
\end{document}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = runin ,
  solution/print = true
}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{choices}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[choices]{label=(\Alph*)}

\begin{document}
```

[image]

That being said I'd suggest to use a dedicated package for questions and answers like [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) for this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = runin-nr ,
  headings-format = \normalfont ,
  solution/print = true
}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{choices}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[choices]{label=(\Alph*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \bfseries Mock Exam
\end{center}

\begin{question}
  Here's a question.
  \begin{choices}
    \item Option A
    \item Option B
    \item Option C
    \item Option D
    \item Option E
  \end{choices}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  (A) \par\medskip
  Some stuff telling you why the answer is (A).
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  Here's another question.
  \begin{choices}
    \item Option A
    \item Option B
    \item Option C
    \item Option D
    \item Option E
  \end{choices}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  (C) \par\medskip
  Some stuff telling you why the answer is (C).
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, you convinced me. `exsheets` is very nice, and the documentation actually explains it well! I'll try this out and let you know how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: If you want solutions and questions separated then remove the line `solution/print = true` in my code and add `\printsolutions` where you want the solutions printed (as long as it is *after* the questions). Section 11 *Printing the solutions* has the details.

Comment: @cgneider - Thank you for telling me about this package! It's a lot easier than I thought it would be! I only have one question - is there any way I can customize the enumerate number? In a previous project, we did `\begin{enumerate}[label=\Large\textbf{\arabic*.}]` to number the questions. Thank you again!

Comment: You mean the number of the questions? Yes. Default is bold which I disabled in my example with `headings-format = \normalfont`. Default is `\normalsize\bfseries` so you probably want `headings-format = \Large\bfseries`